# How can i go to the first while loop if the answer is 'N' in this code:

Tags: c++

```
while (true)
{
    cout << "1- Add record" << endl;
    cout << "2- List records" << endl;
    cout << "Select your choise: ";   cin >> n;
    switch (n) {
    case 1:      m1.addrecord(); 
        while (true) {
            cout << "Add another record? (Y/N): ";  cin >> ch;
            if (ch == 'Y')
                m1.addrecord();
            else if (ch == 'N')
                continue;
            }
    case 2:     m1.listrecords(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `continue` to `break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a loop, `continue` tells the loop to perform the next iteration of the loop, skipping the rest of the code in the loop.

In a loop, `break` tells the loop to exit the loop, even if the condition to end the loop has not been satisfied.

Since your `while` loop's condition is `true`, it will never end; your two possible choices cannot cause the loop to exit.

Therefore, your solution is to change `continue` to `break`, as @R_Kapp said in his comment.

```
while (true) {
    cout << "Add another record? (Y/N): ";  cin >> ch;
    if (ch == 'Y')
        m1.addrecord();
    else if (ch == 'N')
        break; // This is changed from `continue` to `break`
}
```

As user @LogicStuff points out, you are also missing a `break` statement at the end of your cases, in your `switch` statement. Since this is not part of the question, you'll have to look into it yourself.

Please view this link for further reference on `switch` statements:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: OP also forgot to `break` the `case`.

Comment: You are correct, so I've added a reference for them to use, as it is not their original question.

Comment: You should accept answers if they have been helpful to you. Glad I could help.